# Caching externally-loaded data in a static variable

Tags: caching, static, rust, ffi

I'd like to load data from a file, then cache this data (including quite large arrays) in a static variable. This obviously is not the preferred way of doing this, but:

1. I'm writing a Rust library invoked by a C(++) program, and don't currently have any objects which out-live invocation of the Rust functions. Using a static avoids me having to hack up the C code.
2. The program doesn't do anything concurrently internally, so synchronisation is not an issue.

How can this be done in Rust?

I have found [lazy-static](https://github.com/Kimundi/lazy-static.rs) which solves a similar problem, but only for code not requiring external resources (i.e. items which could in theory be evaluated at compile time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do the initialization at program start, but you can do it at the first method call. All further calls will access the cached value instead of recomputing your value.

Since rust forbids things with destructors inside static variables, you need to do your own cleanup management. Logically this means you need unsafe code to break rust's safety system. The following example uses a `static mut` variable to cache a heap allocated object (an `i32` in this case).
The cacheload function works like a Singleton.

Just remember to call cachefree() from c after you are done.

```
use std::{ptr, mem};

static mut cache: *const i32 = 0 as *const i32;

unsafe fn cacheload() -> i32 {
    if cache == ptr::null() {
        // do an expensive operation here
        cache = mem::transmute(Box::new(42));
    }
    return *cache;
}

unsafe fn cachefree() {
    if cache != ptr::null() {
        let temp: Box<i32> = mem::transmute(cache);
        cache = ptr::null();
        drop(temp);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x;
    unsafe {
        x = cacheload();
        cachefree();
    }
    println!("{}" , x);
}
```

Comment: Except, I suppose, that memory leaks at program exit don't really matter (on most modern OSes). So maybe this does work without extending the C API.

Comment: Have you been introduced to [`Once`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Once.html)?

Comment: using Once would break the possibility to repeatedly use cachefree and cacheload in arbitrary order and number, but in general it is a much better way to initialize once.

Comment: `Once` would work if I didn't have to modify my cache more than once.

Comment: You should probably use a Mutex if you want this to be thread-safe; and by now you can use `Box::into_raw()` to convert the Box into a `*mut i32`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It seems there's already OnceLock(). Example of using that below.

I was looking for an answer to this exact question. Since it's preferrable to avoid `unsafe`, I came up with the following, which should also be thread safe:

```rust
fn get_or_create_static_cache() -> &'static Something {
   static CACHE = RwLock<Option<&Something>> = RwLock::new(None);

   // If there is a previously cached value, return that.
   // Will potentially block while another thread is building the data.
   if let Some(s) = *CACHE.read().unwrap() {
        return s;
   }

   // Acquire write lock before constructing the data to
   // prevent any other threads from concurrently building the data too.
   let mut w = CACHE.write().unwrap();

   // Handle the improbable case that two threads simultaneously got 
   // through to acquiring the write lock.
   if let Some(s) = *w {
       return s;
   }

   let data:Something = ... // Construct the data that we want to cache.

   // Allocate it on the heap and leak into a 'static reference.
   let s = Box::new(data).leak();

   // Update the RwLock.
   *w = Some(s);

   // The write lock is automagically released on exit.
   return s;
}
```

---

EDIT: It seems there's already `OnceLock()` which does exactly the same thing:

```rust
fn get_or_create_static_cache() -> &'static Something {
  static CACHE: OnceLock<Something> = OnceLock::new();

  CACHE.get_or_init(|| {
     ... //Build the object
  })
}
```

Comment: You should probably use [`OnceCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/cell/struct.OnceCell.html) (or `LazyCell` on nightly) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @cafce25 OnceCell won't work as it doesn't implement Sync and can't be safely stored in a static. However, that made me look at OnceLock, which is better.